# Names can't be empty while using data_frame in Rstudio

Tags: r

I am trying to make a table with only patient IDs (`participant_id`), so i used the following code to extract this column from an other table I just made:

```r
patient_IDs <- data_frame (IDs$participant_id)
```

However, it keeps giving the following error:

```txt
Error in 'data_frame ()':
names can't be empty.
empty name found at location 1
```

All the cells in this column are filled, so i don't understand what it means by the names are empty.

I appreciate if anyone helps me to solve it

Comment: just provide a column name: `patient_IDs <- data_frame (id = IDs$participant_id)`

Comment: Note that `tibble::data_frame()` is deprecated and you don't really need that nor it's replacement (`tibble()`) here, plain `patient_IDs <- IDs["participant_id"]` is enough.